# Volume of a parallelepiped, given 8 vertices

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, matrices, geometry, trigonometry

Given the eight vertices $(0,0,0)$, $(3,0,0)$, $(0,5,1)$, $(3,5,1)$, $(2,0,5)$, $(5,0,5)$, $(2,5,6)$, and $(5,5,6)$, find the volume of the parallelepiped.

I'm having trouble finding the 1 vertex and 3 vectors needed to find the volume. The closest four vertexes I found so far are $(0,0,0), (3,0,0), (0,5,1), (3,5,1)$...is using those four vertexes correct? Any starting hints to point me in the right direction?

Comment: No. Notice that your 4th equals the sum of the 2nd and 3rd: $$(3,5,1) = (3,0,0) + (0,5,1)$$ So you want a different 4th; you can identify it as some of the subsequent vertices are equal to a sum involving it.

Comment: But note that by adding constant vector $ (2,0,5)$  to first 4 points you get next 4 points; and that there is no change of y-coordinate, and so it is like a shear deformation from rectangle to parallelogram.Sketching by hand in 3D projection helps.

Comment: In theory it can, but that would a degenerate parallelepiped in the sense that it has zero and lie entirely in a plane. Your parallelepiped is not degenerate.

Comment: It is natural to focus on the vertex at $(0,0,0)$. What are the three other vertices whose squared distances from $(0,0,0)$ are smallest? Like @SimonS says, your fourth point has $3^2+5^2+1^2$ which is not on the "top-3" of smallest squared distances. *Addition:* Wait, for some very long and slim parallelepipeds it may happen that the surface diagonal on the tiny side on the end is shorter than the long edge.

Comment: You can confirm that by making sure the four other vertices are simple sums of the first three (excluding (0,0,0)), in the sense that the coefficients in the sum are 1 or 0. That way you know we're dealing with a volume which has parallel sides and that the first three you have found give the three directions of the 12 sides.

Comment: Ok. What's your final answer?

Comment: @SimonS: The vertex is $(0,0,0)$ and the three vectors are...$(3,0,0), (0,5,1), (2,0,5)$?

Comment: And the volume?

Comment: @SimonS: Is the volume of the parallelepiped the absolute value of the determinant of the matrix: $\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 5 & 1 \\ 2 & 0 & 5 \end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: Yes ............ my work is done ;-)

Comment: @SimonS: Thanks so much for the help! :) If you would like to write an answer for it, I will upvote & select it.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
If the origo is among them, the set of vertices of a parallelepiped is of the form
$$\{0,\ a,\ b,\ c,\ a+b,\ a+c,\ b+c,\ a+b+c\}$$
for some vectors $a,b,c$. 
Then write the coordinates of these $a,b,c$ in a matrix and calculate its determinant.